# How to decode http packet from raw buffer tcp data in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, http, tcp, decoding, packet

I am new to nodejs. I am trying to decode data from tcp packet which now only contains HTTP information header and body. I read on RFC that HTTP headers are in character set  ISO-8859-1 . In Nodejs this is represented as latin1.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5987

So I am trying to print HTTP header from the pcap file which contains HTTP packets.

```
 const httpInformation = tcpInfo.data.toString('latin1', 0, 20);
              let lines = httpInformation.split('\r\n')
              console.log("http info: ", lines[0])
```

But I see something like '¾ì2iæqÍ@wl1¯<ê=b'

Also when I try to get different header keys' value, nothing gets printed:

```
if (httpInformation.startsWith('GET ')) {
             
                console.log("contains GET ")
              }
```

Any help with this is highly appreciated! Please let me know what is my mistake here? How to decode HTTP headers from raw tcp data? Are there any nodejs libraries I could use?

Comment: Why are you building your own http parser?  Why not just use one of the many built-in ways of receiving http responses?

Comment: @jfriend00 could you please suggest a link to one with an example? I tried looking for one but could not find. Since I need to decode http headers from raw packets stream.

Comment: Well, if you're using nodejs, you can make http requests with the built-in `http.request()` or the newly added `fetch()` interface or popular third party libraries are `got()` (my favorite) and `axios()`.  You may have to show more of how your tcp connection gets started for us to help in more detail.

Comment: I get raw packets from captured from another app through grpc. Link Layer, IP Layer and Transport Layer headers have been decoded. So I have tcp data now. I need to decode http headers from this.

Comment: @jfriend00 could you please show me an example of http headers parsing for raw buffer data from tcp payload using any of the available frameworks in nodejs?

Comment: What are the source and destination TCP port numbers?